# Flight delay: duration of stay and validity

Tags: overstaying, visa-expiration, schengen-visas

While applying for a Schengen visa, I mentioned in my cover letter to grant a few extra days to cover for any flight delays. So I was granted one day extra in duration of stay and 2 weeks of extra validity.

Now if my flight is delayed or cancelled and hence extending my stay by more than a day, then is my visa valid or not? Can I re-enter the city in such a scenario, given that the validity is still there for 2 more weeks?

Answer (score 2):

Your visa has two numbers.

- Duration of stay, which is the maximum number of days in the Schengen zone (first and last days count full).
- Validity of the visa, which is the time period when you can make your visit, up to the number of days set by the duration.
- Finally there is the number of entries.

So they gave you the option to stay one day longer than originally planned, or to postpone the **entire** trip, both arrival and departure, by up to two weeks.

Imagine you have a visa with 10 days duration and a validity from January 1st to January 13th. Then your options are to visit either January 1st to 10th, or January 2nd to 11th, or January 3rd to 12th, or January 4th to 13th.